# Problem with login screen

Tags: keyboard, screen, crash

I'm an ultra nooby beginner with Linux and Kubuntu, so please be patient :) Since yesterday I've got a stupid problem. When  I turn on my PC, and when my login screen shows up, after 2-3 second it crashes - I see everything in horizontal lines, but I can write my password  and enter the system. Unfortunately, after login in, screen still looks like before login.

But when I'll log out with keyboard combo, the login screen look's normal. After second login everything is fine till I restart the PC. Then everything repeats. Additionally, since there is a problem with screen, I've also noticed that my spacebar often doesn't work when I press it, so I need to press it again. Didn't tried it with other keys.

I have no idea what is happening. Please help! :)

---

Now, when I log in the OS (after second time, when everything's fine), KDWallet want's me to enter password and log into it. Got this few times since yesterday.

Comment: What is your video card model?

Comment: It's Asus Radeon R7 240 2 GB DDR3

Comment: And what version of Ubuntu?

Comment: Kubuntu 15.10. I'm using it for about 2 months now. Everything was fine till Wednesday. On Tuesday evening there were some updates, I've updated the OS and the next day this mess was here.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a graphics card issue or display manager issue. Try `sudo dpkg-reconfigure <display manager>` (change with `kdm/lightdm`, whichever you have), will help to solve if problem is with the display manager.

Hope it will help, thanks

Comment: I tried it and the answer was, that I don't have the manager installed

Comment: Use commands: 'sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install kdm && sudo apt-get install -f -y'. Select kdm as default when prompted. Hope it helps, thanks

Comment: This bug is still here.

Comment: Probably it's a graphics card issue then. My knowledge is not able to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds it may be some hardware conflict.   If you're able to login, then call up a terminal window or use keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>

Do:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

This is will update any library versions.  Sometime this could help repair problems.  This actually worked for me once.   If this doesn't work then you may need to either check your hardware configuration on your computer to check that it is compatible with linux.

Comment: I  tried it, the problem is still here

Answer (score 0):

Do you use SDDM display manager, version 0.13? If so, try

```
sudo apt-get install sddm=0.11.0-0ubuntu11
```

in order to force installation of the previous SDDM version 0.11 and reboot your system.